# Error when executing the scenario in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to implement Rdma over INET in Omnet++ and I have no problem to build the INET project but, when I run the .ini file I get the following errors and I don't know how to solve it.

Pd: I have omnet 6.0pre11 and INET 4.3.2

> /home/usuario/omnetpp-6.0pre11/samples/inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to inet::Rdma::handleCrashOperation(inet::LifecycleOperation*)
> /home/usuario/omnetpp-6.0pre11/samples/inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to inet::Rdma::handleStartOperation(inet::LifecycleOperation*)
> /home/usuario/omnetpp-6.0pre11/samples/inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to inet::Rdma::handleStopOperation(inet::LifecycleOperation*)
> /home/usuario/omnetpp-6.0pre11/samples/inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to inet::RdmaHeader::RdmaHeader()
> /home/usuario/omnetpp-6.0pre11/samples/inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to ::RdmaHeader::setSrcPort(unsigned short)
> /home/usuario/omnetpp-6.0pre11/samples/inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to typeinfo for inet::RdmaHeader
> ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to inet::Rdma::getEphemeralPort()
> ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to inet::Rdma::handleCrashOperation(inet::LifecycleOperation*)
> ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to inet::Rdma::handleStartOperation(inet::LifecycleOperation*)
> ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to inet::Rdma::handleStopOperation(inet::LifecycleOperation*)'
> ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to inet::RdmaHeader::RdmaHeader()
> ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to inet::RdmaHeader::setSrcPort(unsigned short)
> ../../inet/src/libINET.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for inet::RdmaHeader'

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide more details about your implementation of RDMA or provide [mcve]?

Comment: I have already solved the problem. It was that mandatory methods were missing, in case someone has the same problem. In my case these methods have been handleStartOperation, handleStopOperation and handleCrashOperation.